# Draining cooling system & Distilled Water

Tags: cooling-system, cooling

I saw a video on Youtube where someone changed the cooling liquid of their car's cooling system by first draining the system and, then, by putting distilled water in it. Once the distilled water is in the system, he drove the car for the distilled water to clear any cooling liquid that would be left in the cooling system.

My question being: isn't dangerous to drive a car around only with distilled water in the cooling system? Even if only driven for a short amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem. The coolant liquid helps to elevate the boiling point and it also prevents freezing when left in the engine in winter. I think it should be OK for a while. Although your engine will probably boil sooner, so be sure that it won't overheat..

Comment: Insightful. Thank you. Now, I understand why some coolants are 50% coolant and 50% water.